# MimeTypeMap fail to return extension for a filename that contains spaces

Tags: java, android

I am trying to retrieve an extension from a file using **MimeTypeMap.class** of ***android.webkit*** package.

```
File file = new File(someUrl); 
String ext = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

ext returns null or empty if the file.getName() contains blank spaces!

How to solve it?

Comment: `java.net.URLEncoder.encode(file.getAbsolutePath())`

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
    public static String getMimeType(File file) {
            String extension = getExtension(file.getName());
            if (extension.length() > 0)
                return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension.substring(1));

            return "application/octet-stream";
        }

public static String getExtension(String uri) {
        if (uri == null) {
            return null;
        }

        int dot = uri.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (dot >= 0) {
            return uri.substring(dot);
        } else {
            // No extension.
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where does getExtension() come from?

Comment: I know I can work with String to get a substring at last index of "." after checking if the file object is not a directory. Doing so I will not need MimeTypeMap! But MimeTypeMap is set for that. Now why doesn't it accept spaces?

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
ContentResolver cr = get ContentResolver();
String type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().GetExtensionFromMimeType( cR.getType(uri));
```